# compare two input values in input validation html javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to compare two inputs minimumN and maximumN, and display an alert if the logic is not satisfied, I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Minimum N</th>
        <td>
            <input id="minN" onkeyup="MinimumNValidate()" type="text" maxlength="50">
        </td>
        <th>Maximum N</th>
        <td>
            <input id="maxN" onkeyup="MaximumNValidate()" type="text" maxlength="50">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
function MinimumNValidate() {
    var min = document.getElementById("minN").value;
    var max = document.getElementById("maxN").value;
    if (min > max) {
        alert("Minimum value must be lesser than maximum value.");
    }
}

function MaximumNValidate() {
    var min = document.getElementById("minN").value;
    var max = document.getElementById("maxN").value;
    if (max < min) {
        alert("Maximum value must be greater than minimum value.");
    }
}
```

but this is not working, and the alert is being displayed even when the minN is less than maxN, can you point out the mistake in my code ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Comment: It is not a typo, it is parse Int issue but yes.. it has a typo there.

Comment: It's a simple typo, but really, off-topic / not about programming?

Comment: sorry about the typo, i have corrected the typo, but still it doesn't seem to be working, can you help ?

Comment: @Sachin Can you tell us which inputs are causing the fail? I bet it is a parseInt issue, try this for both validation methods:   
       `var min = parseInt(document.getElementById("minN").value);` 
       `var max = parseInt(document.getElementById("maxN").value);`

Comment: sorry about the typo, even after correction, the same problem persists, can you help ?

Comment: yes it is parseInt, the issue has been resolved, thanks

Comment: I have nominated for re-opening. @pawel questions are closed not to be buried, but to be improved (and if not, then buried). In this case it probably was a little quick on the draw, but hey, no one is perfect.

Comment: There you go, please accept an answer so the question can be closed... make sure you update your question to know what the problem was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few things here

close the input elements:

```
if(maxN<min) {
```

Should be

```
if(max<min) {
```

Finally, you are not comparing integers but strings so..

```
5<9
555<9
1000<20
```

Its "alphabetic"

You need to parse them to int.

```
parseInt(max) and parseInt(min)
```

...

```
function MinimumNValidate(){
       var min = parseInt(document.getElementById("minN").value);
       var max = parseInt(document.getElementById("maxN").value);
       if(min > max) {
           alert("Minimum value must be lesser than maximum value. " + min + " > " + max );
       } 
 }    

    function MaximumNValidate(){
       var min = parseInt(document.getElementById("minN").value);
       var max = parseInt(document.getElementById("maxN").value);
       if(max<min) {
           alert("Maximum value must be greater than minimum value."  + min + " > " + max );
       } 
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

In the second function MaximumNValidate(), you have the line of code

```
if(maxN<min) {
```

which should be

```
if(max<min) {
```

Comment: +1, but it's annoying as hell ;) http://jsfiddle.net/FyAnR/ (@Sachin, use `onchange` or add some more checks);

Comment: even after that, i am getting the same output, is the logic correct ?

Comment: @Sachin, the output is correct, but `''<1`, so it alerts before you even start to type the max value. Same for typing `100` (three alerts!) in the min, and then typing the max `1` then `0` (two alerts!) then `1' (no alert).

Comment: i have used the onchange event, the number of alerts have decreased.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function checknumber(theForm) {   
 if (parseInt(theForm.num2.value) != (parseInt(theForm.num1.value)+1)) 
    { 
    alert('enter the correct year in intermediate');
            return false;
            } 
     return true;
            
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<head> </head> 
    <body> 
        <form action="../" onsubmit="return checknumber(this);">     
<label> tenth graduation </label> 
      <input type="number" name="num1"  autocomplete="off"><br> <br>
<label> Intermediate </label>
       <input type="number" name="num2" autocomplete="off">
     <input type="SUBMIT" value="year validation">
       </form>
```